# Move files to a new folder for every model run

Tags: matlab, loops

After running the executable I want to store some newly created files for example, newfile_1.txt, newfile_2.txt to a new folder for every run (Run_1, Run_2...). I can only create one folder which overwrites the moved files after every run. Is there a solution to this?

```
% set working directory
cd('E:\Tutorial\SimFolder\');
runpath = 'E:\Tutorial\SimFolder\';

%%
myDir = 'E:\Tutorial\New_Files\'; %gets directory of files to be copied
myFiles = dir(fullfile(myDir,'*.txt')); %gets all txt files in struct

%%
for k = 1:length(myFiles)
  baseFileName = myFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myDir, baseFileName);
  copyfile(fullFileName,[runpath 'file.txt']); %copy & rename file
  system('program.exe'); %run executable
  movefile([runpath 'newfile_1.txt'],'E:\Tutorial\Results\Run_1'); %this part needs to change
end
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the script, I would simply look in the `E:\Tutorial\Results\` folder for any directories called `Run_N` (note that [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) in Matlab outputs a struct that has an `isdir` field which will tell you if a given file is actually a directory), find the one with the largest N, create a new folder `Run_N+1`, and then set that as the destination folder in the final line of your loop.